# Enable content conflicting with display form for login in MS Access

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a Access database as front end to a SQL Server back end database. I created a simple form to get the name of the user and I set this form as a display form. Now the value typed in this form is stored into a table in sql server, but since it is the backend db, it requires logging in to the SQL Server. Now the problem is: when I try to open access from a different PC, the security warning comes up and asks to enable content. Now the display form does not allow me to enable content and the vba code will not run unless I enable content. I need some help to find a solution to this problem. Can I somehow delay the display form from showing up until the enable content is clicked?
Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your "Access User" form modeless; thus you'll have the possibility to Enable Content.

Comment: I needed the Form to be a Modal form, So I just added the vba code to set the Modal property to true on the OnCurrent event of the Form and its working perfectly. Now, after clicking the enable content the form becomes Modal. @CST-Link thanks for your help.